# agm-info-window infoWindow Opened by default angular ionic3

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-google-maps

In Ionic 3 + Angular 4 I have the following code :

```
 <agm-info-window #infoWindow>
                        <strong>{{data.title}}</strong><br>
                      </agm-info-window>
```

The marker opens the bubble only when clicked 
How to make it open by default ?
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try adding **[isOpen]="true"** to **agm-info-window**, like this:

```
<agm-info-window [disableAutoPan]="false" [isOpen]="true" #infoWindow>
```